# Passing argument from main to function in C

Tags: c, atoi

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    // Compile this program with:
    //      cc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o rot rot.c


        #define ROT 3

        //  The rotate function returns the character ROT positions further along the
        //  alphabetic character sequence from c, or c if c is not lower-case

        char rotate(char c)

        {

                // Check if c is lower-case or not
                if (islower(c))
                {
                        // The ciphered character is ROT positions beyond c,
                        // allowing for wrap-around
                        return ('a' + (c - 'a' + ROT) % 26);

                }
                else
                {
                        return ('A' + (c - 'A' + ROT) % 26);;
                }
        }

        //  Execution of the whole program begins at the main function

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {


                     for (int j = 2; j < argc; j++){
                        // Calculate the length of the second argument
                        int length = strlen(argv[j]);

                        // Loop for every character in the text
                        for (int i = 0; i< length; i++)
                        {
                                // Determine and print the ciphered character
                            printf("%c" ,rotate(argv[j][i]));
                            printf("%c" ,rotate(argv[j][i])-ROT);
                            printf("%d",i+1);
                            printf("\n");

                        }

                        // Print one final new-line character
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                        // Exit indicating success
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                return 0;
        }
```

I am struggling with a program that rotates the given characters by the amount user type in as the first argument of argv.

Now I need to modify the program to achieve this. The question says I can use àtoi` function to do that.

My confusion is that How can  my `argv[1]` value in Main be passed into function rotate (Variable ROT)?

The ideal output would be (using terminal in MAC)

```
./rot 1 ABC
AB1
BC2
CD3
```

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what the desired output should be for a given input.

Comment: the posted code has a significant logic error,  It does not properly handle anything but a...z and A...Z  all other characters, spaces, tab, semicolon, etc etc will cause the program to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROT` is a macro. You can't change it at runtime. Use a variable instead.

(You need to error check [strtol()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) and ensure there are as many `argv[]` passed before using them -- strtol() is better than atoi as helps detect errors).

```
 int rot = (int)strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);


 printf("%c" ,rotate(rot, argv[j][i]));
 printf("%c" ,rotate(rot, argv[j][i])-ROT);
```

and change it to:

```
char rotate(int rot, char c) {
 ...
}
```

and use `rot` instead of `ROT`.